# External page to appear inside an anchor div

Tags: html, anchor

So, I have this HTML:

```
    <a href="external.html">External Link to appear inside the anchor div</a>

    <div name="anchor">


    </div>
```

How can I get to the external link to show inside the anchor div?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use an ajax call to show your external page inside a frame

Comment: So you want to display the HTML contents of `external.html` inside `<div name="anchor">`?

Comment: Use iFrame to load external page

Comment: @AfromanJ yes, exactly. Also, I need this to be done on HTML. Maximum Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

If requested source do not allow you, you cannot get page content inside your div. You will get this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Important:**

If remote resource owner is you, you can grant permission like below;

1. Enable headers module on apache
2. Configure apache host conf : **Header set
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin "your_client_url"**
3. Reload apache

You can refer [here](http://harthur.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/configure-apache-to-accept-cross-site-xmlhttprequests-on-ubuntu/) for more detail.

My scenario was like below for test. You can see that you cannot get remote content with ajax because of different domain protocol

You can use `iframe` instead of remote page load.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.themesearch.org" onclick="javascript:;">External Link to appear inside the anchor div</a>

<div name="anchor">


</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('a[href="http://www.themesearch.org"]').on('click', function() {
    $( 'div[name="anchor"]' ).load( $('a[href="http://www.themesearch.org"]').attr("href"), function() {
        alert( "Your external page loaded" );
    });
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BeBgc/5/

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this way it doesn't open inside the div. Otherwise it should still appear the text inside the <a> tags. And I need them to still appear.

Comment: I forgot to update code. However, requested source do not allow to load page that way. It gives error I have update my answer. You can fetch it inside iframe

Comment: But a source that allows can be loaded this way, inside the div? How can I grant it will allow?

Comment: You cannot grant external source. That can be granted only resource owner. Granting operation is simply adding some header to request header on remote source.

Comment: I'm asking how to grant it because I'm the owner of the external webpage. In fact, this will two pages of the same project. e.g. project/index.html + project/external.html. And I wan't to click a link in index.html and open content inside external.html inside a div of the index.html. But I would like not to use frames...

Comment: I have edited my answer. Which programming language or webservice do you use on backend? I can help you by using that information

Comment: We only have HTML+CSS+JavaScript(just a little). And now is a small project. Only after the project we will begin with PHP+MySql. So, for now, I can only use html+css+js

Comment: Are you serving those html,css throught apache?

Comment: No, not yet. its all local. but the idea is to getting it online. Why you asking?

Comment: You need to serve remote resource throught web service in order to load it. You can set header on apache configs

Comment: hmm, I didn't understand well what you said. But I will show this thread to my teacher. You know any link showing information about how to do that?

Comment: In order to reach remote source, you need to use url like: "http://your_url/file.php". This means, you have a web server, this web server serves you specified page. You need to put some conf to your web server in order to access that page. If you are in some domain, you can use relative url like "file.php"

Comment: I have a domain already. It will subsitute this webpage www.verticalvideo.pt . Also, you put "file.php", it must really be "*.php" or can this be done in another format?

Comment: It can be another format. You have domain? You can edit http config for that domain